# What are some things I could do to speed up a PyQt4 QTableView that is showing constantly changing data?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview

I am running a code that displays a QTableView, which is attached to a data model that is constantly being updated. The table is about 100 rows by 40 columns, which I feel is not a lot.

My problem is, that whenever I run the code and the TableView is shown, it is extremely slow. Be it scrolling up/down, left/right, or entering values, there is a noticeable time lag (~2-3 seconds).

I would like this lag to be eliminated as much as possible. I've already disabled the resizing of columns & rows to contents, and that helped speed up the view. What are some of the other things I could do to achieve this? And in general, what are the memory/CPU hogs in a QTableView?

Comment: Please show us your code in the form of an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be useful for us if we can reproduce the issue ourselves. It's now unclear if there is a bug in your code or if the model is just updated too often. So, how often is the data updated?

Comment: The the data is updated approximately once per second. Which means that each and every cell is updated, so around 4000 updates per second. I will try to share the code once I'm back home.